# Schedule Python Selenium Script on Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku

I have a Python selenium script that I want to run everyday except Friday and Saturday at 7:15 in the morning. I am using Advanced python scheduler and I have created a file named clock.py. I want to what to add to the Procfile so that it automatically runs. I have tried clock: python colock.py but it doesn't work. I have tried the project code on my Local Machine with the scheduler and It works perfectly fine.

This is my python advanced scheduler code

```
from main import fill_form
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()

sched.add_job(fill_form, 'cron', day_of_week='sun,mon,tue,wed,thu', hour=7, minute=15)

sched.start()
```

Comment: Provide the code which you tried and the error you are getting

Comment: I edited the post with my Clock.py code. I have tried this code on my local machine and it works. I have added Clock: python clock.py in my heroku Procfile and It doesn't run the script. I have even changed the timzeone to my local timezone in heroku config vars

Answer (score 0):

Did you start the clock process?
From your terminal: `heroku ps:scale clock=1`

Comment: Yes, I started it from the heroku cli and I even made sure it was turned on in the Resources tab.